# "Run HQL Query" not appearing in Netbeans

Tags: hibernate, netbeans, hql

I just want to run the HQL query without writing java code for it. I tried to right click on hibernate.cfg.xml file but I could not find "Run HQL Query" option in the menu. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to check hql run in netbeans for hibernate projects

- Right-click the project node in the Projects window and choose Clean and Build.
- Right-click hibernate.cfg.xml in the Projects window and choose Run HQL Query to open the HQL query editor.
- Select hibernate.cfg from the drop down list in the toolbar.
- Test the connection by typing the query in the editor and clicking the Run HQL Query button  in the toolbar.

refer http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html#06

Comment: In fact "Run HQL Query" does not appear when I right click hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: first clean and build project after that try to right click on hibernate.cfg.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Hibernate.cfg.xml file in **src ->default-package**, not in WEB-INF **->** classess